# Rails: How do I make select send an object instead of a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a drop down menu of users, when I select one and submit my form the controller receives the user object as a string rather than the object itself. How do I make a menu whereby the user object itself is submitted?

```
<%= form.select :recipient, @users %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `collection_select` instead of `select`.

`Select` is for rendering information from a drop down menu **it is not meant for dynamic database information.** `Collection_select` on the other hand is meant to pull things from a database, it allows you more options such as `collection_select :label, :collection, :server information, :display information`

Do this instead:

```
<%= form.collection_select :recipient, @users, :id, :email %>
```

Comment: this is a little misleading. both methods work on an array of objects.  the difference between them is that `collection_select` allows the flexibility of letting the developer decide the label and value methods.